# Trouble scraping a table into R

Tags: javascript, html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying and failing to scrape the table of average IQs by country from [this web page](https://iq-research.info/en/page/average-iq-by-country) into R. I'm trying to follow the process described in [this blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/), but I can't seem to find the right XPath.

Here's the code I'm using, with a placeholder for the XPath to that table:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://iq-research.info/en/page/average-iq-by-country" 

xpath <- [xpath copied from Chrome using SelectorGadget]

IQ <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath) %>%
  html_table()
```

I tried using the selector gadget in Chrome to find the right XPath, but there are a bunch of elements that seem to paint the desired table blue when I toggle over them. I tried copying the XPaths for most or all of those elements and using them as `xpath` and got two types of results: either `{xml_nodeset (0)}`, or `Error in tokenize(css) : Unexpected character '/' found at position 1`.

I would appreciate help figuring out how to get to that table (and ones like it I might encounter in the future).

Comment: It's using javascript to render the table. You'll need to use RSelenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @hrbrmstr's pointer about javascript being the issue, I was able to get this done using using `phantomjs` and following [this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scraping-javascript-generated-data-with-r#gs.KecQrjI). Specifically, I:

1. Downloaded phantomjs for Windows from [this site](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) to my working directory;
2. In Windows Explorer, manually extracted the file `phantomjs.exe` to my working directory (I guess I could have done 1 and 2 in R with `download.file` and `unzip`, but...);
3. Copied the 'scrape_techstars.js' file shown in the tutorial identified in step 1, pasted it to Notepad, edited it to fit my case, and saved it to my working directory as "scrape_iq.js";
4. Back in my R console, ran `system("./phantomjs scrape_iq.js")`;
5. Back in Windows Explorer, looked in my working directory to find the html file created in step 4 ("iq.html"), right-clicked on that html file, and selected Open with > Google Chrome;
6. In the Chrome tab that launched, right-clicked on the page and selected Inspect;
7. Moused over the table I wanted to scrape and looked in the Elements window to confirm that it is a node of type "table"; and, finally,
8. Ran the R code below to scrape that table from "iq.html".

Here's the .js file I created in step 3 and used in step 4:

```
// scrape_iq.js

var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'iq.html'

page.open('https://iq-research.info/en/page/average-iq-by-country', function (status) {
  var content = page.content;
  fs.write(path,content,'w')
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Here's the R code I used in step 8 to scrape the table from the local html file `phantomjs` had created and get a data frame called `IQ` in my workspace.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

IQ <- read_html("iq.html") %>%
  html_nodes('table') %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]]
```

And here's the head the data frame that produced:

```
> head(IQ)
  Rank     Country  IQ
1    1   Hong Kong 108
2    1   Singapore 108
3    2 South Korea 106
4    3       Japan 105
5    3       China 105
6    4      Taiwan 104
```