# Rvest Scraping- Why won't this css/xpath selector work anymore?

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

Built a crude scraper for scraping pitching statistics from Baseball-Reference.com.  About a year ago, the scraper worked fine for grabbing pitcher names and the links associated with each pitcher, but after recently running the following code, it's returning empty character vectors.

```
library(rvest)
library(curl)

year = "2017" # Declare a year for looking up stats

appURL <- paste(c("http://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/",year,"-standard-pitching.shtml"),collapse = "")
mlbpitcherdata <- read_html(appURL)

mlbpitchers <- mlbpitcherdata %>% html_nodes('#players_standard_pitching_clone > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > a') %>% html_text()
mlbpitcherlinks <- mlbpitcherdata %>% html_nodes('#players_standard_pitching_clone > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > a') %>% html_attr("href")

> mlbpitcherlinks
character(0)
> mlbpitchers
character(0)
```

Here's the current HTML workup of the site with the pitcher name highlighted:
[image: Baseball Reference Pitchers]

Can someone give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong here?  Can someone propose a solution for scraping the names, links, and ultimately the table here?

Comment: It looks like they're now using javascript to render that table. Here's a question I asked a while ago that may offer one solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428993/trouble-scraping-a-table-into-r. I'm sure there are others.

Comment: That table  is actually a comment in the raw html source. Presumably scripts  on the page manipulate to render. `<!--
   <div class="table_outer_container">
      <div class="overthrow table_container" id="div_players_standard_pitching">` I couldn't immediately find the duplicate question, but this has been answered before. The fix is to read as text with `readLines`, remove the beginning and end comment with, say, `gsub,` then use `read_html`

Comment: See the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434984/readhtmltable-in-r-only-bringing-back-first-two-tables-from-basketball-reference which has the same problem

Comment: Selecting columns of a table is hard because there is no direct css selector. Follow something like these examples (given for teams): `mlbpitchers <- mlbpitcherdata %>% html_nodes('#all_teams_standard_pitching table') %>% html_table(); 
mlbpitcherlinks <- mlbpitcherdata %>% html_nodes('#all_teams_standard_pitching a') %>% html_attr("href")`

Comment: Here is a similar question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505619/scraping-commented-out-tables-in-r